# Click expand on html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to do Expand/collapse on click (See pic below).

When a person clicks on the PLUS(+) sign, it expands and the signs change itself to Minus(-) sign and when a person clicks on Minus Sign it Collapse and again changes to Plus Sign.

Here is the Image,
[image]

Comment: newbie or not, you need to show what you have tried and where you got stuck. Not just some one help me by doing the work for me! Ask yourself how do you think it works? Some one clicks, then opens, clicks again it closes. Is the content being added on click or is it already there from the start? etc. Work through it first.

Comment: @javaBean007 i am not asking for someone to write the complete code for me. I just want the name what it is called and then i can start learning about it ON MY OWN!

Comment: I support @Maz341 , at least I found the answer through his post. Here is a place to ask and learn. If you have the time to point your finger at someone and argue what to do what not to do, why not just leave your answer?Don't just down vote and nothing leave.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for Tree view. If its you can achieve this using jquery plugin

[jQuery-Folder-Tree-Plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Powerful-Multi-Functional-jQuery-Folder-Tree-Plugin-zTree/demo/en/)

Answer (score 1):

I found this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jqwidgets/3rt8z/) with nice implementation of what you are looking for.

```js
var data = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Corporate Headquarters",
    "budget": "1230000",
    "location": "Las Vegas",
        "children": [{
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Finance Division",
        "budget": "423000",
        "location": "San Antonio",
            "children": [{
            "id": "3",
            "name": "Accounting Department",
            "budget": "113000",
            "location": "San Antonio"
        }, {
            "id": "4",
            "name": "Investment Department",
            "budget": "310000",
            "location": "San Antonio",
            children: [{
                "id": "5",
                "name": "Banking Office",
                "budget": "240000",
                "location": "San Antonio"
            }, {
                "id": "6",
                "name": "Bonds Office",
                "budget": "70000",
                "location": "San Antonio"
            }, ]
        }]
    }, {
        "id": "7",
        "name": "Operations Division",
        "budget": "600000",
        "location": "Miami",
            "children": [{
            "id": "8",
            "name": "Manufacturing Department",
            "budget": "300000",
            "location": "Miami"
        }, {
            "id": "9",
            "name": "Public Relations Department",
            "budget": "200000",
            "location": "Miami"
        }, {
            "id": "10",
            "name": "Sales Department",
            "budget": "100000",
            "location": "Miami"
        }]
    }, {
        "id": "11",
        "name": "Research Division",
        "budget": "200000",
        "location": "Boston"
    }]
}];

var source = {
    dataType: "json",
    dataFields: [{
        name: "name",
        type: "string"
    }, {
        name: "budget",
        type: "number"
    }, {
        name: "id",
        type: "number"
    }, {
        name: "children",
        type: "array"
    }, {
        name: "location",
        type: "string"
    }],
    hierarchy: {
        root: "children"
    },
    localData: data,
    id: "id"
};

var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source, {
    loadComplete: function () {

    }
});
// create jqxTreeGrid.
$("#treeGrid").jqxTreeGrid({
    source: dataAdapter,
    altRows: true,
    width: 680,
    theme:'energyblue',
    checkboxes: true,
    ready: function () {
        $("#treeGrid").jqxTreeGrid('expandRow', '1');
        $("#treeGrid").jqxTreeGrid('expandRow', '2');
    },
    columns: [{
        text: "Name",
        align: "center",
        dataField: "name",
        width: 300
    }, {
        text: "Budget",
        cellsAlign: "center",
        align: "center",
        dataField: "budget",
        cellsFormat: "c2",
        width: 250
    }, {
        text: "Location",
        dataField: "location",
        cellsAlign: "center",
        align: "center"
    }]
});
$("#jqxbutton").jqxButton({
    theme: 'energyblue',
    height: 30
});
$('#jqxbutton').click(function () {
    $("#treeGrid").jqxTreeGrid('checkRow',2);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.energyblue.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/jqx-all.js"></script>

<div id="treeGrid"></div>
<input type="button" style="margin: 20px;" id="jqxbutton" value="Check a row" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your image says you want something like JSON Tree.

you can do this by using several Jquery plugins. here is the one - github link, [Z-Tree](https://github.com/zTree/zTree_v3)